# Information about Microsoft USB Product ID 1260

Tags: usb

I managed to extract some information about a USB device, as follows:

```
[Device, Port 0]
Type: Unknown
ProductID: 1260
VendorID: 1118
  === Interface ===
  Class: Vendor Specific
  SubClass: 255
  Number: 0
  Protocol: 255
  Type: 4
```

VendorID 1118 is Microsoft, however I can't determine what ProductID 1260 is.

Does anyone know of a listing that I can search to find out? I know that all USB devices need to be registered with the USB ppl but I can't find a search screen on their site for this type of information.

Any help would be kewl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the list [here](http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids), that is a Windows Phone (Zune).

Look for 04ec instead of 1260 (i.e. the list is in hex but your result was in decimal).

Comment: How do you even go about looking for this kind of information?! Thanks.

Comment: @kurtnelle I think what I eventually ended up asking Google was `"productid" "vendorid" microsoft`. I then scanned page titles until I saw something likely (Linux sites often have lists like this to help others create drivers or get info like you are). Just luck and persistence.

Comment: @Todd, so look at the linux sites. Got it.